# 2d array during runtime in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, runtime-error, user-input

Why does the code below gives runtime error when the values of m and n are LARGE?
When n and m are equal to 1000000, it shows java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.
Because of this my code fails for large input of n and m.
Is there any other way to do this without getting OutOfMemoryError ?

```
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   int n = sc.nextInt();
   int m = sc.nextInt();
   int a[][] = new int[n][m];
```

Comment: What error are you getting? And how is `a` defined?

Answer (score 0):

The runtime error happens when N or M are large because of a lack of memory.

You can initialize the array using the fill method.

```
int [][]a = new int[N][M];
Arrays.fill(a, 0);
```